# Undo git revert from other branch

Tags: git

I made two commits on a feature into master ***oops*** that should have been made in a feature branch.

To fix the immediate issue, I created a new branch off of master that now contains my feature code. Then, I used `git revert sha` to create two new commits that undid those two commits in master.

Now that I've done my testing and I'm happy with the results of those two commits, I need to merge my branch back into master, which will essentially mean undoing the two revert commits.

Comment: So... what's the question?

Comment: You can also just move your master back prior to the erroneous commits (using `git reset`) after creating the feature branch (saves you the revert commits)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply do the merge as you normally would. The fact that it has the same (or similar) effect as reverting a reversion is irrelevant.